# React Native with axios getting warning [Unhandled promise rejection: Error: Request failed with status code 401]

Tags: react-native, axios, warnings

[The warning message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CuA6T.jpg)

I try to make a react native app to see post from wordpress rest api. I use axios and i get this message.

I have two screens. The Homescreen and an item screen in which i make a second request for the media.

Here is the Homescreen.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, Dimensions } from 'react-native';import axios from 'axios';
import { ScrollView } from 'react-native-gesture-handler'
import HTML from 'react-native-render-html';
import GArticleItem from './GArticleItem';
class HomeScreen extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state= {isLoaded: false , gArticles: []}
}

componentDidMount(){
  axios.get(`https://psaddict.gr/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?categories=10`)
  .then(res => {
    this.setState({ isLoaded: true, gArticles: res.data  });
  }).catch(function(error){
    console.log("Not responding"); 
  });
}

render() {
const {isLoaded, gArticles} = this.state;
if(isLoaded) {
return (<View>
    <ScrollView horizontal={true}
        // contentContainerStyle={{ width: '100%' }}
        showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
        scrollEventThrottle={200}
        decelerationRate="fast"
        centerContent = {true}
        pagingEnabled >
      {gArticles.map(gArticle => (<GArticleItem key={gArticle.id} gArticle={gArticle} /> ))}
     </ScrollView>
  </View>
);
}else {
  return(
    <Text>Loading...</Text>
  );
   }
 }
 }

 export default HomeScreen;
```

And the Item screen in which i call the api for the media

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, Image, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import HTML from 'react-native-render-html';
import axios from 'axios';

class GArticleItem extends Component {
    state = {
    imgUrl: '',
    author: '',
    isLoaded: false
}
static propTypes = {
    gArticle: PropTypes.object.isRequired
}

componentDidMount(){
    const { featured_media, author } = this.props.gArticle;

    const getImageUrl = axios.get(`https://psaddict.gr/wp-json/wp/v2/media/${featured_media}`);
    const getAuthorUrl = axios.get(`http://psaddict.gr/wp-json/wp/v2/users/${author}`);

    Promise.all([getImageUrl, getAuthorUrl]).then(res => {
        this.setState({
            imgUrl: res[0].data.media_details.sizes.full.source_url,
            author: res[1].data.name,
            isLoaded: true
        })
    });
}

  render() {
  const { title } = this.props.gArticle;
  const {author, imgUrl, isLoaded} = this.state
  if(isLoaded){
    return (
        <View>
            <Image style= {styles.mainImage} source= {{uri: imgUrl} } />
          <HTML html= {title.rendered} />
            <Text>by</Text> 
            <Text>{author}</Text>
        </View>
      );
  }else{
      return(
          <Text>Loading...</Text>
      )
  }
 }

}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
mainImage: {
    width: '100%',
    height: 250,
    alignSelf: 'center'

   }
  });


export default GArticleItem;
```

if I use a catch block at the Item screen I get this error

```
[Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: undefined is not an object (near '...}).catch(function (err...')]
```

Comment: Promise.all needs a catch block more than anything else because there are multiple requests and the chance of failure is higher. A

Comment: if I use a catch block i get this error : [Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: undefined is not an object (near '...}).catch(function (err...')]